# Refactoring two methods down to one

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have two methods that almost do the same thing. They get a `List<XmlNode>` based on state OR state and schoolType and then return a distinct, ordered `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`. I know they can be refactored but I'm struggling to determine what type the parameter should be for the linq statement in the return of the method (*the last line of each method*).

I thank you for your help in advance.

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getAreaDropDownDataSource() {
    StateInfoXmlDocument stateInfoXmlDocument = new StateInfoXmlDocument();
    string schoolTypeXmlPath = string.Format(STATE_AND_SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, StateOfInterest, ConnectionsLearningSchoolType);
    var schoolNodes = new List<XmlNode>(stateInfoXmlDocument.SelectNodes(schoolTypeXmlPath).Cast<XmlNode>());
    return schoolNodes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Attributes["idLocation"].Value, x.Value)).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Distinct();
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getStateOfInterestDropDownDataSource() {
    StateInfoXmlDocument stateInfoXmlDocument = new StateInfoXmlDocument();
    string schoolTypeXmlPath = string.Format(SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, ConnectionsLearningSchoolType);
    var schoolNodes = new List<XmlNode>(stateInfoXmlDocument.SelectNodes(schoolTypeXmlPath).Cast<XmlNode>());
    return schoolNodes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Attributes["stateCode"].Value, x.Attributes["stateName"].Value)).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Distinct();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract nodes retrieving to separate methods/properties. I also suggest to have different properties/methods for extracting school and state nodes:

```
private List<XmlNode> GetNodes(string xPath)
{
    XmlDocument stateInfoXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    return new List<XmlNode>(stateInfoXmlDocument.SelectNodes(xPath)
                                                 .Cast<XmlNode>());
}

private List<XmlNode> SchoolNodes
{
    get { return GetNodes(String.Format(SCHOOL_PATH, LearningSchoolType)); }
}

private List<XmlNode> StateNodes
{
    get { return GetNodes(String.Format(STATE_PATH, StateOfInterest)); }
}
```

Use union of school and state nodes for retrieving area nodes:

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetAreaDropDownDataSource()
{
    return SchoolNodes.Union(StateNodes)
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Attributes["idLocation"].Value, x.Value))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .Distinct();
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetStateOfInterestDropDownDataSource()
{
    return SchoolNodes
        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Attributes["stateCode"].Value, x.Attributes["stateName"].Value))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
        .Distinct();
}
```

Also you can use different selectors of type `Func<XmlNode, KeyValuePair<string, string>>` and pass them to method which will create data source:

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetDropDownDataSource(
        List<XmlNode> nodes,
        Func<XmlNode, KeyValuePair<string, string>> selector)
{
    return nodes.Select(selector)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                .Distinct();
}
```

Comment: @lc. thanks, didn't notice that. Changed from property to method

Comment: Thank you, there is some really great ideas here :)

Answer (score 2):

I feel like while they are both returning an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`, these methods are semantically quite different in content. Therefore, I would keep the two methods and extract only the repeated code to a third. Something like:

```
private List<XmlNode> getSchoolNodes(string xmlPath, params object[] values)
{
    StateInfoXmlDocument stateInfoXmlDocument = new StateInfoXmlDocument();
    string schoolTypeXmlPath = string.Format(xmlPath, values);
    return new List<XmlNode>(stateInfoXmlDocument.SelectNodes(schoolTypeXmlPath).Cast<XmlNode>());
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getAreaDropDownDataSource() {
    var schoolNodes = getSchoolNodes(STATE_AND_SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, StateOfInterest, ConnectionsLearningSchoolType);        
    return schoolNodes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Attributes["idLocation"].Value, x.Value)).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Distinct();
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getStateOfInterestDropDownDataSource() {
    var schoolNodes = getSchoolNodes(SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, ConnectionsLearningSchoolType);
    return schoolNodes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Attributes["stateCode"].Value, x.Attributes["stateName"].Value)).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Distinct();
}
```

---

You could go as far as the following, but I wonder if this is overengineering the problem and creating overhead calling the two `Func`s.

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getSchoolNodeDataSource(Func<XmlNode, string> keyFunc, Func<XmlNode, string> valueFunc, string xmlPath, params object[] values)
{
    StateInfoXmlDocument stateInfoXmlDocument = new StateInfoXmlDocument();
    string schoolTypeXmlPath = string.Format(xmlPath, values);
    var schoolNodes = new List<XmlNode>(stateInfoXmlDocument.SelectNodes(schoolTypeXmlPath).Cast<XmlNode>());
    return schoolNodes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyFunc(x), valueFunc(x))).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Distinct();
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getAreaDropDownDataSource() {
    return getSchoolNodeDataSource(x => x.Attributes["idLocation"].Value, x => x.Value,
        STATE_AND_SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, StateOfInterest, ConnectionsLearningSchoolType);        
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getStateOfInterestDropDownDataSource() {
    return getSchoolNodeDataSource(x => x.Attributes["stateCode"].Value, x => x.Attributes["stateName"].Value, 
        SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, ConnectionsLearningSchoolType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Foo(
    string schoolTypeXmlPath,
    Func<T, string> keySelector,
    Func<T, string> valueSelector)
{
    return (
        from XmlNode x in StateInfoXmlDocument().SelectNodes(schoolTypeXmlPath)
        orderby x.Key
        select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keySelector(x), valueSelector(x)))
        .Distinct()
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getAreaDropDownDataSource() {
    return Foo(
        string.Format(STATE_AND_SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, StateOfInterest, ConnectionsLearningSchoolType),
        x => x.Attributes["idLocation"].Value,
        x => x.Value);
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getStateOfInterestDropDownDataSource() {
    return Foo(
        string.Format(SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, ConnectionsLearningSchoolType),
        x => x.Attributes["stateCode"].Value,
        x => x.Attributes["stateName"].Value);
}
```